# Different java recursive outputs

Tags: java, recursion

I am working on this leetcode problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-closed-islands/description/

The recursive code I have written produces different result for the test case below if we returning xx instead of yy.

Test case is:

```
grid = [[0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0],[1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1],[1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0]]
```

My code:

```
class Solution {
    int R;
    int C;
    public int closedIsland(int[][] grid) {
        R = grid.length;
        C = grid[0].length;

        boolean[][] visited = new boolean[R][C];
        int numIslands = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < R; ++r) {
            for (int c = 0; c < C; ++c) {
                if (grid[r][c] == 1 || visited[r][c]) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (dfs(r, c, grid, visited)) {
                    numIslands++;
                }
                // numIslands += dfs(r, c, grid, visited);
            }
        }

        return numIslands;
    }

    public boolean dfs(int r, int c, int[][] grid, boolean[][] visited) {
        if (r < 0 || r == R || c < 0 || c == C) {
            return false;
        }

        if (grid[r][c] == 1  || visited[r][c]) {
            return true;
        }

        visited[r][c] = true;
    
        boolean left = dfs(r - 1, c, grid, visited);
        boolean right = dfs(r + 1, c, grid, visited);
        boolean up = dfs(r, c - 1, grid, visited);
        boolean bottom = dfs(r, c + 1, grid, visited);
        
        System.out.println(r + "_" + c);
        boolean yy = left && right && up && bottom;
        boolean xx = dfs(r - 1, c, grid, visited) 
                    && dfs(r + 1, c, grid, visited) 
                    && dfs(r, c - 1, grid, visited) && dfs(r, c + 1, grid, visited);
        // System.out.println("yy : " + yy);
        // System.out.println("xx : " + xx);
        // return left && right && up && bottom;
        return xx;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know the reason?